# KnexJS RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: node.js, knex.js

I have the following  knex query in nodejs.
The goal of this query is to delete all the rows in the table `rule` where it's NOT a foreign key in any of the three tables: `rule_set`, `rule_in_progress`, and `rule_pending`. That is, delete all the rows in `rule` that are essentially unused.

```
deleteUnusedRules(txn) {
    const conn = txn ? txn : knex;
    return conn.table('rule').delete()
        .whereNotIn('rule.id', function() {
            this.table('rule_in_progress').select('rule_in_progress.rule_id')
                .union(this.table('rule_pending').select('rule_pending.rule_id')
                    .union(this.table('rule_pending').select('rule_pending.rule_id')
                        .union(this.table('rule_set').select('rule_set.rule_id'))
                    )
                );
        });
}
```

But it throws the following error

```
stack=RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

I can't find any solution online to this.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that because you are using you subquerybuilder `this` for all the union queries, something inside knex makes cyclic references to that query...

Basically every time you call `this.table` you are not creating a new subquery, but you are modifying the same builder.

Maybe you tried to do this:

```
deleteUnusedRules(txn) {
    const conn = txn ? txn : knex;
    return conn.table('rule').delete()
        .whereNotIn('rule.id', conn.table('rule_in_progress').select('rule_in_progress.rule_id')
                .union(conn.table('rule_pending').select('rule_pending.rule_id')
                    .union(conn.table('rule_pending').select('rule_pending.rule_id')
                        .union(conn.table('rule_set').select('rule_set.rule_id'))
                    )
                )
        );
}
```

Above all union select queries are creates as separate query builder instances, which are not sharing state.